# Using existing securityGroup and pem file in jclouds - Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jclouds

I'm starting to use jclouds to manipulate EC2 instances. Therefore, I have the following method:

```
private ComputeService compute;

public void add(Integer instances) {
        try {
            logger.info("------------------------------------------------------");
            logger.info(String.format(">> adding node to group %s%n", this.groupname));
            // Default template chooses the smallest size on an operating system
            // that tested to work with java, which tends to be Ubuntu or CentOS
            TemplateBuilder templateBuilder = this.compute.templateBuilder();
            // note this will create a user with the same name as you on the
            // node. ex. you can connect via ssh publicip
            Statement bootInstructions = AdminAccess.standard();

            // to run commands as root, we use the runScript option in the template.
            templateBuilder.options(runScript(bootInstructions));

            Template template = templateBuilder.build();
            // add a custom security group

            NodeMetadata node = getOnlyElement(this.compute.createNodesInGroup(this.groupname, instances, template));
            logger.info(String.format("<< node %s: %s%n", node.getId(),
                        concat(node.getPrivateAddresses(), node.getPublicAddresses())));
            logger.info("------------------------------------------------------");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            logger.info("------------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
```

Please assume that the authentication is correct and
`groupname = default`. When I execute

```
this.compute.add(1);
```

Even though one single instance is created, `jclouds` will create a new `security group` and `key pair` every time. I do have my existing `foo.pem` file, and the `default` security group. For example:
`security group = jclouds#default`. How can I make use of my existing security group and key value?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use existing security groups or key pairs, you can do it by providing them to the template builder:

```java
templateBuilder.securityGroups(<existing security groups>);
templateBuilder.as(AWSEC2TemplateOptions.class).keyPair(<existing key pair>);
templateBuilder.options(runScript(bootInstructions));
```

Note that in order to use the `keypair` method you need to cast the options to the AWS class, since that option is not available in the portable interface.

Also note that when using key based access to access the nodes via SSH (to run the script), jclouds will have to present the "private key" to the node. You have two options: load the key into the ssh-agent beforehand, or use the `templateOptions.overrideLoginPrivateKey` to provide your private key so jclouds can properly log into the node.